# Display all the distinct values in 1 ssrs letter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hi I am creating an ssrs report (which is a letter format). And in the letter format, if a owner has highest sales for 3 products in same store I need those products to be listed in the same letter instead of 3 different letters. I have written an expression for the body of the letter. But that expression is taking all the products that has highest sales and generating 3 different letters. May I know how can I embed the product names within the body of the letter?

Sample That I need:

Hi Doc,

It has really great that you are making a huge impact on our product sales.
In our recent survey, we found that your store had the highest sales for following products:

- Comforters
- Cosmetics
- Toys

Please continue this xyz.

NA Dept.

Comment: You seem to need a tutorial - try searching "ssrs form letter". If your datasource contains one row per owner and product (for three rows total for each owner), then you will need to use groups to do this.

Comment: i'd do this in sql and simply use SSRS to present. You need to show some data with the mentioned scenario for us to help